# I can't run the Steam for a multitude of reasons, I think

Tags: steam

listen I'm new to Ubuntu, I have no idea what I'm doing
I'm trying to get steam to work and I have no idea what's wrong with it at this point.
here's what comes up when I use the "steam command

```
ayden-russo@Point:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/ayden-russo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Startup - updater built Sep 13 2021 22:00:59
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1631572918)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  44
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/ayden-russo/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1631572918)
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Checking for update on startup
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Checking for available updates...
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1631572918)
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1631572918, installed version 1631572918, existing pending version 0
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Nothing to do
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Verifying installation...
[2021-09-14 21:33:54] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-09-14 21:33:55] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.17-6744061
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:18369): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:18369): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210914213354_1.dmp[18408]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210914213354_1.dmp
/home/ayden-russo/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 772: 18369 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
ayden-russo@Point:~$ assert_20210914213354_1.dmp[18408]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20210914213354_1.dmp[18408]: response: CrashID=bp-eb37e735-4d29-405e-83ac-bfb3e2210914
assert_20210914213354_1.dmp[18408]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20210914213354_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-eb37e735-4d29-405e-83ac-bfb3e2210914''
```

Comment: well I swiftly found a lot of the things but it's still not working

```
ayden-russo@Point:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/ayden-russo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? How did you install steam what exact commands?